# How to include object/associative array into object (js)

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

I have the following code not working:

```
function validation() {
this.stuff=stuff {
    letters_numbers:/[^\s\"\'\w]/,
    letters:/\w/
}
this.val_string=val_string;
    function val_string (type,data){
        var x=stuff[type];
        console.log(x.test(data));
        return x.test(data);
    }
```

}

The `stuff` should be a associative array or object that contains key-value pairs.
What I'm looking for is a way to include an assoc array or object within the one above.

Comment: For future questions, I'd suggest getting the syntax right (unless you really can't do that) and then describing what you're seeing vs. what you're expecting. Sometimes people can "guess" answers, but often it just wastes the time of those who want to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function validation() {
var stuff = this.stuff = {
    letters_numbers:'/[^\s\"\'\w]/',
    letters:'/\w/'
}
    function val_string (type,data){
        var x=stuff[type];
        console.log(x.test(data));
        return x.test(data);
    }
    this.val_string=val_string;
}
```